# Enable SSL for mongoDB using hibernate OGM

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, mongodb-java, hibernate-ogm

I am using hibernate OGM to interact with mongoDB. As part of business requirement, I need to enable `ssl` for the communication between mongodb and my java application.

I see in mongodb documentation that using the mongodb-java-driver, it is as simple as turing the ssl flag to true in the connection string. How can I do this in hibernate?

**===== UPDATE based on the only given answer ======**

Hibernate OGM version 4.2 uses mongodb Java driver version 2.13 which doesn't include the ssl property in MongoClientOptions.Builder class. I can not upgrade hibernateOGM version because its still either beta or alpha. I tried explicitly upgrade the java driver version but then I started getting exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.options.impl.WriteConcernOption`

**======== Update 2 ==============**

I looked into the mongodb java driver documentation and found that setting `socketFactory` option to `SSLSocketFactory` might to the trick (see https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#java). But seems like hibernate OGM 4.2 is not picking up the following property to use the SSLSocketFactory for creating mongo client:
`hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.socketFactory=SSLSocketFactory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable SSL using the following property:

```
hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.sslEnabled = true
```

you can also set:

```
hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver.sslInvalidHostNameAllowed = true
```

HIbernate OGM uses the `com.mongodb.MongoClient`and you can set all the properties in `com.mongod.MongoClientOptions` using the prefix `hibernate.ogm.mongodb.driver`.

Check the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/ogm/5.0/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html#mongodb_specific_configuration_properties) and [MongoClient.Builder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) for more details.

Comment: I have updated the question in light of your suggestion but now trapped in another problem. Do you have any other option to point at?

Comment: Currently, there is an open issue for this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-975

Comment: One workaround might be to extend the MongoDBDatastoreProvider method: protected MongoClient createMongoClient(MongoDBConfiguration config) and use the parameter `hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider`.